# How much current can arduino ground absorb?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am currently working on an LED 4x4 cube, so here is my pre planned circuit diagram.

[https://easyeda.com/editor-mobile/#id=ffca9f3303f242a185b950b0bee4fa29|](https://easyeda.com/editor-mobile/#id=ffca9f3303f242a185b950b0bee4fa29%7C)

[image]

1. I am to connect 220ohm to each positive terminals.(16)
2. I am to use 4 transistors(2n2222) for 4 negative layers of which, collector terminal will be connected to the negative terminal layers , base will be connected to 4 analog pins through 1k ohm, and emitter to be connected to the GND pin of arduino. Using transistor as a switch.

Can my studio ground get damaged if connected directly without a resistor.

If no?

Is there any way to make it?

Explanation with circuit diagram will highly be preferred...

Thanks for your precious time...

Comment: Ordinary LEDs take 20 mA at most, and they are already bright enough (to my taste at least) at 10 mA or even less. If you get 1 A for 16 LEDs there is probably something wrong with your current-limiting resistors.

Comment: But if I connect resistor with higher ohm, the cube won't be able to run a single LED when needed as resistance will be too high for a single one, or if I connect low resistors that might either burn my LEDs or produce amps, btw, let's head to the main discussion point, can arduino ground tolerate 5 amps at max? If u have an idea please do share with me via sending a diagram. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are going to multiplex your LEDs, first you will design the DC current to a brightness of your linking. Second, you will multiply this current with the number of multiplexing steps. This results in a peak current for each LED, with breaks in between. Practically all LEDs withstand such a driving. Finally, you will multiply this current with the number of LEDs switched on at the same time. This is the expected maximum current that your circuit shall handle.

Comment: The best approach in my experience is to let that high current not on the Arduino. Design your driver's circuit separated, and just connect the grounds.

Comment: That's right @busybee but, I am to make driver for sure , but before it, I wd like to test it connecting it bare (maybe resistors)on arduino pins.

Comment: Those measurements don't make any sense. You can't get 1A of current with 16 x 220Ohm resistors, even if the forward voltage of the LEDs is 0V. I'd expect at most 200mA. So **something is wrong**. Either you have a short, or you multimeter is of. If your UNO is connected via USB, you can (theoretically) only get 500mA before the polyfuse cuts out the power.

Comment: Since you will be multiplexing you don't have to worry about the other layers, as only a single layer will be on at the same time. So you **don't** also multiply the current, of the one layer, by four.

Comment: @Gerben yeah I recently spotted my mistake thanks for the advice, but if I make a voltage amplifier using transistor and then, I guess I will be able to run all the LEDs together right?

Comment: there is no reason why the LED current should run through any part of the arduino

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "voltage amplifier". But running 16 leds with 220Ohm resistors will only give you 200mA, so I don't see any problem here. The only problem I see is with the columns. The Arduino pins can source the ±14mA, but the ATMega has some limitations on the total amount of current, total current for certain groups of pins. The maximum total current the ATMega328P can supply to all pins combined is 200mA. Ports C0 - C5, D0- D4, ADC7, should not exceed 150mA. Ports B0 - B5, D5 - D7, ADC6, XTAL1, XTAL2 should not exceed 150mA.

Comment: PS could you share what the mistake was?

Comment: @Gerben , my mistake was R=1/R + 1/R , as resistance of a standard LED is almost 48 ohm and they were in parallel connection,  (tried to pick a paralled connection of the LEDs row from layer 1)  R = 1/48*4 (because there are 4 LEDs in a row of a layer) , so answer is 0.0833, let's inverse it , 1 / 0.0833 = 12ohm for each row in a layer. Now, as I = V/R , 3 / 12 = 0.25 ,  =25, something like this....

Comment: What should be the delay() time of blinking those LEDs? delay(10) will be enough I guess

Comment: You want an update rate of at least 50-100Hz, so your eyes don't perceived flicker. So let's go with 100Hz here. Since you have 4 layers, you need to change layers at a rate of 4*100 = 400Hz. Which is every 2.5ms. In my project I'd setup one of the timers to call my ISR every 2.5ms. Then have to ISR update the leds and layer transistors based on a global (volatile) array of all led states. This way the display is updated at a fixed rate, even if some code takes a bit longer. Then the main `loop` only have to change the led state array to show some nice animation.

Comment: You can even add some grayscale to the leds, instead of only ON and OFF. You'd have the multiply the update rate, with the number of grayscale levels.

Comment: @Gerben, I am not only including ON OFF but also dimming and other animations too and for that, as per my calculations, '''delaymicroseconds(2);''' should work fine so that human eye can't recognize it and also I can do as much animations as I like in a single layer at a time.

Comment: 2µs is only 32 clock cycles. You can't do a whole lot in 32 clock cycles. My last project updated it's leds every 52µs, and just the code updating the display used around 30µs of that. The other 20µs where to run the animations. I a bit doubtful if you can run all your code in under 2µs. Also, don't use delay, as you code will take various amounts of time, depending on branching (if-statements etc.). Store the `micros()` value, do your calculations, then wait till there is a 2µs difference between the current value of `micros()` and the stored value.

Comment: @Gerben OK got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your gnd won't get damaged if you source current through it. If u need explanation let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question. It does not matter how much current the arduino ground can adsorb, it was designed for what it needs not what other devices may need. What you want to do is connect all the grounds at the power supply (please tell me you are not using the arduino 5v for this). You might look as MOSFETs as you will have a lower voltage drop and much easier to drive.

Comment: I am connecting all 16 positive pins to arduino pins 0 - 16 through 220ohm resistor and then I am gonna connect the negative layers to the ground using transistor and transistor's base will be connected to the rest of the 4 pins

Comment: None of the power output pins were used